# For Returning Customer Hide or Get Email for added "Repeat Email Address" on WooCommerce Checkout Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've added a Repeat Email Address field on the WooCommerce checkout page with the following add function:

```
// EMAIL Confirmation on CHECKOUT PAGE

add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'email_verification_field_checkout' );

    function email_verification_field_checkout( $fields ) {

    $fields['billing']['billing_email']['class'] = array('form-row-first');
    $fields['billing']['billing_email_verification'] = array(
        'label' => __('Repeat Email Adress', 'woocommerce'),
        'required' => true,
        'class' => array('form-row-last'),
        'clear' => true,
        'priority' => 999,
    );

    return $fields;
    }

// CHECK IF THE TWO EMAILS MATCH !!!
    add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'mycheck_email_addresses');

    function mycheck_email_addresses() {
    $email1 = $_POST['billing_email'];
    $email2 = $_POST['billing_email_verification'];
    if ( $email2 !== $email1 ) {
    wc_add_notice( __( 'Your email addresses don't match!', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
    }
    }
```

Returning Customers can login on top of the page.
WooCommerce then gets the email address for the filed "billing_email" adress.

1) Is there a way to add a function to do the same for the added "billing_email_verification" field?

2) I tried an add function for the case that a Returning Customer logs in on top of the checkout page: In this case I would love to hide the "Repeat Email Address" field for better customer experience. But unfortunately that didn't work. I'm just starting out to understand filters and hooks and would appreciate a helping hand :)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'my_override_checkout_fields' );
function my_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    if( is_user_logged_in() ){
        unset($fields['billing']);
        $fields['billing_email_verification'] = array();
    }
    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/

Answer (score 0):

I've found the mistake in the solution for case 2)
Here is the correct filter for case 2)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'my_override_checkout_fields' );
function my_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    if( is_user_logged_in() ){
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_email_verification']);
    }
    return $fields;
}
```

Anyhow, I would love to learn how I can approach case 1) something with get_value
Does someone know how to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm getting an error message, that the two email addresses don't match (see code on top of the page) so, I have to set/get_value the billing_email_verification = billing_email... how do I do this?